# A problem about Lebesgue measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm doing exercise in "REAL ANALYSIS" of Folland and got stuck on this problem. I got no clue on how to find the set $I$. Hope someone can help me solve this. Thanks so much

> > Suppose $m$ is Lebesgue measure and $L$ is its domain. If $E \in L$ and $m(E) \gt 0$, for any $\alpha < 1$, prove that there is an open interval $I$ such that $m(E \bigcap I) \gt \alpha m(I)$

Comment: Can you use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem?

Comment: No, sorry. This problem appears in the first chapter of the book, so I haven't learnt the theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 
$$
m(E)=\inf\{\sum_j b_j-a_j:\ E\subset\bigcup_j(a_j,b_j)\}.
$$
So, given $\alpha\in(0,1)$, there exist intervals $\{(I_j)\}$ with 
$$
m(E)\geq\alpha\sum_jm(I_j).
$$
Then
$$
\sum_j m(E\cap I_j)\geq m(E)\geq\alpha\sum_jm(I_j).
$$
For this last inequality to hold, it needs to hold for at least one $j$: for such $j$, 
$$
m(E\cap I_j)\geq\alpha m(I_j).
$$

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks so much...

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set with $m(E)>0$, and let $f = \mathbf{1}_{E}$ be the indicator function of this set. For some $x\in E$, we have by the L[ebesgue differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) that
$$\lim_{{I\ni x}\atop{\left|I\right|\rightarrow 0}}\dfrac{m(E\cap I)}{m(I)}=\lim_{{I\ni x}\atop{\left|I\right|\rightarrow 0}}\dfrac{\int_{I}f}{\left|I\right|}=f(x)=1$$
where $I$ is an open interval containing the point $x$. Use the fact that the numerator is bounded from above by $\left|I\right|$ to show the existence of such an interval.

Comment: Can you not use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. This problem appears in the first chapter of the book, so I haven't learnt this theorem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use regularity of Lebesgue measure to find an open set with the desired property. Then use the fact that any open set is a disjoint union of intervals.