# Lebesgue measurability of a set $A = \{\sigma_i \in B\ /\ {2^i}, B \in F\}$ for a a non-principal ultrafilter $F$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, filters

> **Problem** Let $F$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on natural number
>   set $\mathbb N$. Determine if the set $A = \{\sigma_i \in  B\ /\ {2^i}, B \in
>  F\}$ is Lebesgue measurable and if it is measurable, determine its
>   Lebesgue measure.

This is a problem in the lecture download from internet, and now I guess it is not measurable, but my friends think it may be measurable ,and then the measure is $\frac12$.
I don't know how to prove if it is measurable or not.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math.SE! I tried not to alter the meaning of your question with my edit, please tell me if I altered something.

Comment: Relation between $\sigma_i$ and $i$?

Comment: I’m going to guess that $A$ is supposed to be $$A=\left\{\sum_{n\in F}\frac1{2^n}:F\in\mathscr{F}\right\}\;,$$ where $\mathscr{F}$ is the ultrafilter.

Comment: See also:
[Non-measurability of ultrafilter on $\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1130615), 
[Relationships between AC, Ultrafilter Lemma/BPIT, Non-measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/259247), 
[Existence of maximal analytic P-ideal](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270756)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: In line with my comment, I’m going to use $\mathscr{F}$ for the ultrafilter and assume that $A$ is supposed to be

$$A=\left\{\sum_{n\in F}\frac1{2^n}:F\in\mathscr{F}\right\}\;.$$

This makes it likely that $\Bbb N$ here is $\Bbb Z^+$, so that $A\subseteq[0,1]$, and I will assume as much.

- Show that since $\mathscr{F}$ is non-principal and therefore contains the cofinite filter, every dyadic rational is in $A$.

Let $D$ be the set of dyadic rationals.

- Show that for each $x\in[0,1]\setminus D$, $x\in A$ iff $1-x\notin A$.
- Conclude that if $A$ is measurable, then $\mu(A)=\frac12$.
- Adapt this argument to show that $\mu\left(A\cap\left[0,\frac12\right]\right)=\frac14$. Remember that if $F\in\mathscr{F}$, and $F'$ differs from $F$ by a finite set, then $F'\in\mathscr{F}$.
- Further generalize it to show that if $p,q\in D\cap[0,1]$, with $p<q$, then $\mu(A\cap[p,q])=\frac12(q-p)$.

Then use the [Lebesgue density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) or [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673149/a-problem-about-lebesgue-measurable-set?rq=1) to get a contradiction.