# Question about Lebesgue measure of the complement of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have been thinking about a question related to this one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202905/dense-transfer-of-a-set-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-is-it-conull). In summary, the link provided shows that if $A$ is a measurable (Lebesgue) subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with positive measure, and $H$ is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $m((A+H)^c) = 0$.

I am curious about a very similar question. Given a set $A$ with positive measure, can we construct a set $H$, so that $m((A+H)^c) > 0$? Of course, we can do this trivially, that is letting $H = \emptyset$. I believe that maybe this is possible but am not sure. Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Edit: What happens if we impose a restriction on $H$ and $A$? For example, is this still possible if we require $H$ to be countable and $0 < m(A) < \infty$?

Comment: Sure.  Let $A=H=[0, 1]$.

Comment: @RobertShore: Yes of course, I added an edit to make the question a bit more interesting.

Comment: Suppose $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{R}$. Then $m(A)>0$, but $m((A+H)^c)=0$ whenever $H \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @MAPelto: I see thanks for pointing that out. Is this just because in this case $m(A) = \infty$? If we require a finite but positive measure this should be true I would suspect.